# Date value obtained from Masked Textbox and Date from Excel

Tags: c#, datetime, oledb, xlsx

I'm trying to compare a date obtained from maskedTextBox accepting short date, with a date from an excel sheet.
I need to select those rows from excel file that are equal with the date from the maskedTextBox and display them in datagridview.
The problem is that i don't get any results and compiling the code gives no errors.
My code :

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\alekan\Desktop\alm2.xlsx" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT txt" + " " + "FROM [sheet2$] WHERE HHMM = '"+ maskedTextBox1.Text+"'", conn);
     DataSet dstxt = new DataSet();
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
     adapter.Fill(dstxt);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dstxt.Tables[0];
}
```

p.s. txt and HHMM is named columns.

any help is GREATLY apreciated!!!!!

Comment: Did you check the value of maskedTextBox1.Text in debug and verify the condition exists?

Comment: the maskedTextBox automatically fills with a DateTimePcker.  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            maskedTextBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM");
        }

Comment: @MikeG  sorry i misunderstood your reply...seems you were right about that...thank you so much for your reply